How to test a C pointer for whether it points to a struct
I have a linked list structure
struct node {
 int data;
 node next;
}

and a function
struct node *insert_sorted (struct node *nodes, 
  int d) {
  // todo
}

I need to implement this so that, given a new piece of data, it constructs a new node and inserts into the linked list in sorted order.
The first thing I want to check inside of the insert_sorted function is whether nodes points to nothing or something.  By that I don't mean checking whether the pointer is NULL, which I'm familiar with.  I mean that I want to check whether the address nodes holds a node struct or not.  I think if this were Java I might be able to write
if (nodes == null) {
  ...
}

but I don't think there is an analogous thing to do in C.
I know that I could try to manage the nodes pointer so that, if it is non-null then it always points to some struct.  I'll probably end up doing this.
But I just want to know if there exists a more direct way of solving the issue.  Is there any way to take a given non-null pointer and check whether it points to anything or not?

If nodes points to anything other than a struct node, you have a bug.

@dbush what if you malloc but then don't initialize anything in the memory space?

Then it points to an uninitialized struct.  If you allocate memory, you should populate it.

Your code should be written in such a way that it doesn't depend on there being an "empty" node.  A list with no elements should just be a NULL pointer.

@dbush OK, then it sounds like what I mean to ask is: Can you tell if you have an "uninitialized struct" or an "initialized struct"?

No, reading uninitialized memory causes undefined behavior.  My point stands.

@dbush Ok, that's what I was curious about.  Thanks.

@dbush: Reading uninitialized memory produces an indeterminate value, not undefined behavior.

@Addem C lacks the sort of protections you're looking for coming from other languages. You're responsible for making sure data structures are initialized. Instead, use tools such as valgrind and memory sanitizer to detect accidental uses of uninitialized data. Or try a modern systems programming language like Rust.

Note that struct node { int data; node next; } is probably not valid C, even when the missing semicolon is added.  The node type used with node next; has no relation to the struct node that you're defining.  You'd need typedef struct node node; before it, and then you'd say struct node { int data; node *next; }; (see also Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?).  You can't embed a struct node within a struct node; you can embed a struct node * (so you could omit the typedef and use struct node { int data; struct node *next; };)

Checksum/CRC each struct when it is allocated  and every time it is modified, store the check in the struct.  Check each pointer/struct every time you need to read it.


How to test a C pointer for whether it points to a struct

In short, you use your code for this. And logic. As far as the language can go you can not know nothing about it. A pointer is just a variable. It's contents: an address. It could the NULL, it could be a valid address, it could not even be initialized at all. After a free a pointer will still point to non-existing data...
back to the code

I have a linked list structure


struct node {
 int data;
 node next;
}

You have not. This is just a struct for a node. A node is not a list, a list is not a node.
You can for sure name it LinkedList and write a correct program around that, with an actual linked list. But it is not an abstraction for a linked list. It seems to be just a node of a possible linked list of nodes that contains an int value inside each one.
A linked list is a --- possibly empty --- collection of nodes. And it has nothing to do with the data it lists. Each node by its turn contains (or points to) a single unit of data, usually said to be a record.
If your description does not show that your code will be more complicated, less useful and harder to test. You will need loose pointers to beginning of list, counters for size, sometimes pointers to the tail and so on. And code reuse will be complicated.
struct node *insert_sorted (struct node *nodes, 
  int d) {
  // todo
}


The first thing I want to check inside of the insert_sorted function is whether nodes points to nothing or something. By that I don't mean checking whether the pointer is NULL, which I'm familiar with. I mean that I want to check whether the address nodes holds a node struct or not. I think if this were Java I might be able to write

Well, java has no notion of pointers. You can check if a thing is or it is not constructed.
One way to see the problem here is to consider that you want to insert data into a list. It should not even exist the notion of a node to begin with. The abstraction here is not good. Consider
    int so_insert ( int data, List* list);

It could take the value and insert into the list. Return 0 if ok, or a negative status number for an error.
insert_sorted as a name may be a bit over: once you have the notion of order you can have only one insert. A second sort criteria would ruin the order for the first one anyway.
EXAMPLE: an abstraction for a list
These are possible node AND list:
typedef struct st_node
{   struct st_node* prev;  // links
    struct st_node* next;
    int data;  // data
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    Node*  tail;
    Node*  head;
} List;  // a (possibly empty) list of nodes

Node here is in fact a node, List is a list and have the essential metadata: head, tail and size.
Some operations on List:
List* so_create();
List* so_destroy(List*);
int   so_insert(int, List*);
int   so_push_back(int, List*);
int   so_push_front(int, List*);
int   so_print(List*, const char* msg);
int   so_sort(List*);
// helper for multi insert
int so_multi_insert(
    List* list, const unsigned N, ...);

In general we would have a compare function to implement the sorting criteria, and a pointer to it could be in the list. Also the node would point to and not contain a data record. But this is only an example.
About the operations:

push_back and push_front are the C++ names for inserting at tail and head of the list
insert uses ascending order here
since we can insert in order and also at head and tail a sort function is also implemented
for easy insertion a variadic multi_insert is also here
print accepts an optional title to help avoid the classical many printf calls in testing

An example: v1.c
#include "List.h"
int main(void)
{
    size_t N       = 10;
    List*  my_list = so_create();
    srand(240627);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
        so_push_back(rand() % 1000, my_list);
    so_print(my_list, "\nelements back-inserted\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
        so_push_front(rand() % 1000, my_list);
    so_print(my_list, "\n elements inserted at front\n");
    so_sort(my_list);
    so_print(my_list, "\nList is now sorted\n");
    so_multi_insert(my_list, 4, -1, -2, -3, -4);
    so_push_front(-5, my_list);
    so_push_back(-6, my_list);
    so_print(my_list, "\n(-6..-1) inserted\n");
    so_sort(my_list);
    so_print(my_list, "\nList is again sorted\n");
    so_destroy(my_list);
    return 0;
}

This one calls many of the functions to insert data at front and back and then sort the list.
output for the first example
list created

elements back-inserted
    #10 elements in list.
    head element: 161
    tail element: 413

161 31 680 991 329 746 705 839 886 413

[-----]


 elements inserted at front
    #20 elements in list.
    head element: 491
    tail element: 413

491 269 901 863 944 886 243 318 81 682 161 31 680 991 329 746 705 839 886 413

[-----]


List is now sorted
    #20 elements in list.
    head element: 31
    tail element: 991

31 81 161 243 269 318 329 413 491 680 682 705 746 839 863 886 886 901 944 991

[-----]


(-6..-1) inserted
    #26 elements in list.
    head element: -5
    tail element: -6

-5 -4 -3 -2 -1 31 81 161 243 269 318 329 413 491 680 682 705 746 839 863 886 886 901 944 991 -6

[-----]


List is again sorted
    #26 elements in list.
    head element: -6
    tail element: 991

-6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 31 81 161 243 269 318 329 413 491 680 682 705 746 839 863 886 886 901 944 991

[-----]

list deleted

second example: v2.c
#include "List.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    List* my_list = so_create();
    srand(240628);
    // here use use insert to test ordering
    const int N = 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
        so_insert(rand()%1000, my_list);
    so_print(my_list, "\nsorted\n");
    so_destroy(my_list);
    return 0;
}

This one just calls insert to insert some data, print and delete the list.
list created

sorted
    #20 elements in list.
    head element: 21
    tail element: 913

21 100 125 164 248 265 282 286 310 534 558 629 673 689 777 779 817 876 912 913

[-----]

list deleted

the header List.h
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct st_node
{   struct st_node* prev;  // links
    struct st_node* next;
    int data;  // data
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    Node*  tail;
    Node*  head;
} List;  // a (possibly empty) list of nodes

List* so_create();
List* so_destroy(List*);
int   so_insert(int, List*);
int   so_push_back(int, List*);
int   so_push_front(int, List*);
int   so_print(List*, const char* msg);
int   so_sort(List*);
// helper for multi insert
int so_multi_insert(
    List* list, const unsigned N, ...);

a possible implementation of List.c
#include "List.h"

// helper to sort
Node* so_locate_at(List*, size_t);

List* so_create()
{
    List* list = malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (list == NULL) return NULL;
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    list->size = 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "list created\n");
    return list;
}

List* so_destroy(List* del)
{
    if (del == NULL) return NULL;  // no list
    for (size_t i = 0; i < del->size; i += 1)
    {  // delete nodes, 1 by 1
        Node* save = del->head->next;
        free(del->head);
        del->head = save;
    };
    free(del);  // delete list
    fprintf(stderr, "list deleted\n");
    return NULL;
}

int so_insert(int item, List* list)
{
    int result = so_push_back(item, list);
    if (result != 0) return result;  // could not insert...
    if (list->size == 1) return 0;   // was the 1st
    // at least 2
    Node* p = list->tail;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < list->size - 1; i += 1)
    {
        if (p->data >= p->prev->data)
        {
            p = p->prev;
            continue;
        };
        // swap the nodes
        int save      = p->data;
        p->data       = p->prev->data;
        p->prev->data = save;
        p             = p->prev;
    }
    return 0;
}

// return a pointer to the node at position 'pos'
// or 'NULL'. 'pos'starts at 0
Node* so_locate_at(List* list, size_t pos)
{
    if (list == NULL) return NULL;
    if (list->size < 1 + pos) return NULL;
    Node* nd = list->head;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < pos; i += 1) nd = nd->next;
    return nd;
}

// insert all words in the list, sorted
int so_multi_insert(List* list, const unsigned N, ...)
{
    if (list == NULL) return -1;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
        so_insert(va_arg(args, int), list);
    va_end(args);
    return 0;
}

// inserts 'item' at the tail of the list
int so_push_back(int item, List* list)
{
    if (list == NULL) return -1;  // no list
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (node == NULL) return -2;  // no alloc
    node->data = item;
    if (list->size == 0)  // first node
    {
        node->next = NULL;
        node->prev = NULL;
        list->size = 1;
        list->head = node;
        list->tail = node;
        return 0;  // 1st node
    };
    node->next       = NULL;
    node->prev       = list->tail;
    list->tail->next = node;
    list->tail       = node;
    list->size += 1;
    return 0;
}

// inserts 'Item' at the head of the list
int so_push_front(int item, List* list)
{
    if (list == NULL) return -1;  // no list
    Node* node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (node == NULL) return -2;  // no alloc
    node->data = item;
    if (list->size == 0)
    {
        node->next = NULL;
        node->prev = NULL;
        list->size = 1;
        list->head = node;
        list->tail = node;
        return 0;  // 1st node
    };
    node->prev       = NULL;
    node->next       = list->head;
    list->head->prev = node;
    list->head       = node;
    list->size += 1;
    return 0;
}

int so_print(List* list, const char* msg)
{
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "No valid list!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (list->size == 0) return 0;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(
        "\
    #%llu elements in list.\n\
    head element: %d\n\
    tail element: %d\n\n",
        list->size, list->head->data, list->tail->data);
    Node* p = list->head;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < list->size; i += 1)
    {
        printf("%d ", p->data);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n\n[-----]\n\n");
    return 0;
}

int so_sort(List* list)
{
    if (list == NULL) return -1;
    if (list->size < 2) return -2;
    Node* p = list->tail;
    for (Node* q = list->tail; q != list->head; q = q->prev)
        for (Node* p = q->prev; p != NULL; p = p->prev)
            if (q->data < p->data)
            {  // swap the nodes
                int save = p->data;
                p->data  = q->data;
                q->data  = save;
            };
    return 0;
}

code for insert
Here insert is very simple, since we have in fact a List data structure and the operations are isolated:
int so_insert(int item, List* list)
{
    int result = so_push_back(item, list);
    if (result != 0) return result;  // could not insert...
    if (list->size == 1) return 0;   // was the 1st
    // at least 2
    Node* p = list->tail;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < list->size - 1; i += 1)
    {
        if (p->data >= p->prev->data)
        {
            p = p->prev;
            continue;
        };
        // swap the nodes
        int save      = p->data;
        p->data       = p->prev->data;
        p->prev->data = save;
        p             = p->prev;
    }
    return 0;
}

The new node is just  appended at the end and then goes down to their position in a single loop.
code for sort
An insertion at head or tail will destroy the ordering, so a sort function is needed. Here is a simple one:
int so_sort(List* list)
{
   if (list == NULL) return -1;
   if (list->size < 2) return -2;
   Node* p = list->tail;
   for (Node* q = list->tail; q != list->head; q = q->prev)
       for (Node* p = q->prev; p != NULL; p = p->prev)
           if (q->data < p->data)
           {  // swap the nodes
               int save = p->data;
               p->data  = q->data;
               q->data  = save;
           };
   return 0;
}

It is a simple implementation of insertion sort.

A struct node * is always either NULL or points to some struct node, unless you've done something illegal in your code. If you've done things right, the answer to the question is always "yes". If you've done things wrong, you've invoked undefined behavior and so there's no use in asking the question.

So say you do, in the main function, struct node *ns = malloc(sizeof(node));.  That by itself puts a node at ns?  But there isn't data at ns.data or ns.next, right?  How would you know if there's "really" a thing there or not before you've initialized it with data?  Or are you saying that you should never malloc without there being a thing to put in the address?

@Addem It is your responsibility as a programmer to know which memory has been initialized and which hasn't. The C language does not keep track for you. Alternatively, you can switch to a language that simply doesn't have the concept of uninitialized memory, like Java, or a language that keeps track of which variables have been initialized, like Python's UnboundLocalError.

There is nothing illegal about struct node *x = malloc(sizeof *x);, immediately after which x is neither null nor points to an object with effective type struct node, as the C standard specifies it. Further, reading the memory that x points to at that moment would produce an indeterminate value, not undefined behavior. (It also would not be illegal to write struct node *x = (struct node *) &y; provided y has the alignment required for x and points to some other object, although that would be more unusual.)

@Addem An object existing and an object containing valid data are completely different things. ns->data and ns->next exist because you've allocated memory for a struct node, pointed-to by ns. You just can't use those values until you've initialized them.
